# Get pid of a system command

Tags: r

I would like to get the pid of a system command e.g.:

```
system("sleep 10h")
```

I would like the pid even if the command is not launched in the background and is ended. And also the pid of the children commands.
Is it possible ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
system("eval 'echo $$; sleep 10000'", wait = FALSE)
```

if you want your child's process ID, do like this

```
8< --- CUT HERE ---- /tmp/script.sh ---- CUT HERE ---
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10000 &
echo $!
8< -- CUT HERE -- CUT HERE -- CUT HERE -- CUT HERE --
```

And then

```
system("/tmp/script.sh", wait=FALSE)
```

Comment: It is very close to what I need but with this command I get : 'system("eval 'echo $$; sleep 10000'", wait = FALSE) #17401' but with 'ps a | grep sleep' I obtain  :  '17402 pts/12   S+     0:00 sh -c eval 'echo $$; sleep 10000' &
17403 pts/12   S+     0:00 sleep 10000' . Therefore the real pid of the sleep command is +2.

Comment: Of course I could add 2 to the pid from R command but can I be certain that the real pid will always be R pid +2?

Comment: No, you can't be sure of that! Don't do that :)

Comment: But wouldnt it just gives me the pid of sleep command (not the potential child)? And it forces me to run sleep in background.

Comment: By the way I could directly write 'system("eval 'sleep 10&echo $!'", wait = FALSE)'  no?

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well